# Is it possible to download file from instance via aws-api-tools

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I haven't key file .pem for download via scp, is it possible to download via amazon api(I have aws_access_key & aws_secret_key)? I'm tried to find such endpoint(http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/) but ineffectually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not possible. There are many guides online that describe how to replace a lost keypair if that is an option for you.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can take a snapshot of your instance and recreate it with new key-pair. 
That ways you will not loose data. But if there are some services which you ran explicitly they might get stooped.